# Deleting an Empty Directory - Blocked by "It is being used by another process"

Tags: powershell

I've successfully moved the contents out of a directory into another directory and now I'm attempting to clean up the folder. Upon attempting to delete the folder via Powershell I'm receiving an error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" even though the folder is now empty. I have the following syntax:

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force pathtodirhere
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Are you positive that no one has the folder open in Windows Explorer?

Comment: I do have a few files open that were initially in that folder, however I've moved them into another directory. I would have expected to see that error when I moved the files. Any way to kill any process linked to the old directory I'm trying to remove?

Comment: That does not answer the question that I asked...

Comment: The files that are open are test Google Doc files that are indeed open in Google Chrome

Comment: Close everything and see if it works then.

Comment: I suggest you use handle.exe to find what is holding the file or directory open. or you could use this script on MS https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Tools-to-find-and-close-6f1b9175